# I have a problem in styling my HTML table with external CSS file

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and a little CSS. I have a problem in styling my HTML table. I want to style my table specifically. I mean I don't want other tables to get the same style as this table. So I use ID to make it specific. My problem is, when I use the " table, th, td " instead of ID in CSS, it is ok. but when I use Id instead of that, it get mashed up! I think you will get what I say from the picture below.

[this is how table is **without** Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXn2Y.png)

[and this is how table is with id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO0c3.jpg)

I guess I'm missing something or I don't know how to style table with CSS.
My code is below.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px rgba(73, 73, 75, 255) solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(195, 255, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table01">
  <caption>Some info about BVB players</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Player LastName</th>
    <th>Player Jersey Number</th>
    <th colspan="2">nationallity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reus</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Haaland</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>norway</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kobel</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Switzerland</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Dahoud</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Syria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How have you attempted to combine the ID with your existing CSS?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there can be tens on td and th elements inside a table tag and it is not possible to assign a class or id to each and every one of them. i suggest you to assign a class name to the main table tag and select the rest of the td and th elements natively. try this and tell me the result.

```
<table class="table1">

.table1,
.table1 td,
.table1 th{
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px rgba(73, 73, 75, 255) solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(195, 255, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't Id be unique through all the document? I mean as I remember, w3school said that Id should be unique. Anyway, Isn't there anyway to not to define an Id for each line? Isn't there anyway to set the Id for all entire elemenets in one line code?

Answer (score 0):

With the first attempt you're styling all 3 elements, my guess is that you replace "table, th, td" in your css rule with "#table01", meaning that you will only style the table, but not the inner parts of it.
You can use
table#table01, #table01 > th, #table01 > td

To signify "only a table with the id table01, any th inside an object with the id table01 and any td inside an object with the id table01"

```css
table#table01,
#table01 > th,
#table01 > td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 3px rgba(73, 73, 75, 255) solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(195, 255, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table01">
  <caption>Some info about BVB players</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Player LastName</th>
    <th>Player Jersey Number</th>
    <th colspan="2">nationallity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reus</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Haaland</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>norway</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kobel</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Switzerland</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Dahoud</td>
    <td rowspan="2">8</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Syria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```